# wait for jquery first change event to complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select boxes that I'm trying to change.  The second is dependent on the first.  This is what I have so far:

```
$.post('functions.php', {f: 'getdata', param1: parmvalue}, function(data) {

    if (data.platform_seen) {
        $("select#first_box").val(data.first).change();

        if (data.target_release){
            $("select#second_box").val(data.second).change();
        }
    }

}, "json");
```

The first change event works but it immediately triggers the second change event and the values are not present yet from the first change event.

How can I wait for the first change event to complete before triggering the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try wrapping it in `setTimeout()`, with an arbitrarily low time or no time at all like so.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    if (data.target_release) {
        $("select#second_box").val(data.second).change();
    }
});
```

`setTimeout` waits for the current process to finish before executing.  So, calling an anonymous function inside of it will wait for that first change to occur before running the code inside of it.

Not putting a time, or putting a time of `0` will essentially tell it to call this anonymous function immediately after the current process is complete.

Comment: This is an unreliable solution. You can never assume the process has ended.

Answer (score 3):

You can nest them using callbacks -

```
if (data.platform_seen) {
    $("select#first_box").val(data.first).change(function() {
        // starts after first change function completes
        if (data.target_release){
            $("select#second_box").val(data.second).change();
        }
    });
}
```